# Logical (AND, OR, XOR) over Long

Tags: java, logical-operators

I am extending a tool in Java that somehow is capable of applying Logical (AND, OR and XOR) over three Long values.

How is that possible? If it is possible?

Comment: "Logical" as in treating each value as a bool? Why not just logical-OR the three longs together first and then perform the usual operations on the resulting bool?

Comment: There are no logical operators that can be applied to `long` values, only bitwise operators, but they do *look* the same!

Comment: The reason I ask is because the application I am working on has `FunctionBinary.BitwiseAndLong_xyz` and `FunctionBinary.LogicalAndLong_xyz`. So I was wondering what's the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe they wanted to implement [IDL-like logical operators](http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/idl_html_help/Definition_of_True_and_False.html)

*Default Definitions of True and False*

```
Data Type                    True                              False 
====================================================================================
Byte,integer, and long       Odd integers                      Zero or even integers 
Floating point and complex   Non-zero values                   Zero 
String                       Any string with non-zero length   Null string (" ") 
Heap variables               Non-null values                   Null values
```

Comment: It was that. I was able to talk to them.

Answer (score 4):

You can apply bit-wise operators on longs:

- `&` is AND
- `|` is OR
- `^` is XOR

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by not possible? `3 | 4 | 5` is a perfectly valid expression as `3 & 4 & 5`.

Comment: Strictly speaking it would have to be `3L | 4L | 5L` for it to be `long` values ;-)

Comment: @Joachim Sauer - Hahaha, nice:P

Comment: Strictly speaking, that is a bitwise AND and not logical. If there is a no difference that is another story.